# How to remove border of ListView in java fx without using css styles

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

```
ListView listView = new ListView<>();
```

//something like
listview.removeBorder or listview.setborder(Empty border)??

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on the theme you are using in your application.

In Modena (default JavaFx 8+ theme), ListView borders and background are implemented as a background layers, and each layer is just a plain color fill:

```
.list-view {
  -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background; //this line
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
  -fx-padding: 1;
}
```

So, to remove borders you need to remove the first color fill (-fx-box-border) and keep the second one (-fx-control-inner-background, which is color constant with a value #F4F4F4 and represents ListView background color):

```
listView.setBackground(
   new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.valueOf("F4F4F4"), null, null))
);
```

and you'll probably want to remove that 1px padding that was used for borders:

```
listView.setPadding(new Insets(0));
```